# Gradle Shadow Plugin .jar not running on Docker container, no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, docker, gradle, fatjar

I built a fat jar using the [Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) like so:

```
tasks {
    "build" {
        dependsOn(shadowJar)
    }
    shadowJar {
        mergeServiceFiles {
            var path = "META-INF/"
        }
        manifest.inheritFrom(jar.get().manifest)
        manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = "some.main.class.Main"
        manifest.attributes["Implementation-Version"] = version
    }
}
```

This works with no problem when I do `gradle build` and then `java -jar fat_jar_name.jar`, I have tested in `MacOS`, `Windows` and `Ubuntu (WSL)`. The same command works exactly the same on all those platforms, even if the .jar was not locally built, but for some reason it is not working in `Docker` with `eclipse-temurin`.

I am trying to run a .jar file within Docker using:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} fat_jar_name-all.jar

ENTRYPOINT java -jar fat_jar_name.jar
```

I build the image using `docker image build -t image_name .`, and then I am trying to run it using `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 image_name`.

I get this error when running:

```
no main manifest attribute, in fat_jar_name-all.jar
```

I found that this issue is related to not having a `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` file in the exported `.jar`. However, the `fat_jar_name.jar` does contain a manifest file with these contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: some.main.class.Main
Implementation-Version: 3.9.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Is there something I'm missing at the `Docker`, `Gradle` or `Shadow Plugin` level to make this work?

I found [this resource](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/#configuring-the-jar-manifest) for the `Shadow Plugin` about configuring the manifest, but it makes no mention of a `main manifest attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `COPY` command I was using was broken. I used this one instead:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17
COPY build/libs/fat_jar_name-all.jar /
ENTRYPOINT java -jar fat_jar_name-all.jar
```